# The sum of some values of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $$f(x) = \frac{4^x}{2+ 4^x}$$ , then find the value of $$f\left(\frac{1}{101}\right)+ f\left(\frac{2}{101}\right)+ .... + f\left(\frac{100}{101}\right)$$
I have tried to simplify the rule of the function to be
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+2^{-2x +1}}$$ but i did not get any useful thing ?!

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$f(x) = \frac{4^x}{2+ 4^x}= \frac{1}{2^{(1-2x)}+ 1}$$

then

$$f\left(\frac1{101}\right)=\frac{1}{2^{\left(\frac{99}{101}\right)}+ 1}$$

$$f\left(\frac2{101}\right)=\frac{1}{2^{\left(\frac{97}{101}\right)}+ 1}$$

$$\dots$$

$$f\left(\frac{99}{101}\right)=\frac{1}{2^{\left(-\frac{97}{101}\right)}+ 1}=\frac{2^{\left(\frac{97}{101}\right)}}{2^{\left(\frac{97}{101}\right)}+ 1}$$

$$f\left(\frac{100}{101}\right)=\frac{1}{2^{\left(-\frac{99}{101}\right)}+ 1}=\frac{2^{\left(\frac{99}{101}\right)}}{2^{\left(\frac{99}{101}\right)}+ 1}$$

and

$$f\left(\frac1{101}\right)+f\left(\frac{100}{101}\right)=1$$

$$f\left(\frac2{101}\right)+f\left(\frac{99}{101}\right)=1$$

$$\dots$$